# how to install PHP7 on cloudera quickstart?

Tags: php-7, cloudera-quickstart-vm

i'm trying to install php 7 on cloudera quickstart 5.13.0, i put the same commande for centos 7 but i have this error.

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution Error: Package: php-common-7.0.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) Error: Package: php-cli-7.0.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) Error: Package: php-cli-7.0.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) Error: Package: php-json-7.0.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) Error: Package: php-7.0.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libpcre.so.1()(64bit) Error: Package: php-7.0.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: httpd-mmn = 20120211x8664
           Installed: httpd-2.2.15-45.el6.centos.x86_64 (@cloudera-centos-67)
               httpd-mmn = 20051115
           Available: httpd-2.2.15-69.el6.centos.x86_64 (base)
               httpd-mmn = 20051115 Error: Package: php-7.0.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libcrypto.so.10(OPENSSL_1.0.2)(64bit) Error: Package: php-7.0.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit) Error: Package: php-cli-7.0.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64 (remi-php70)
           Requires: libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.15)(64bit)
  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
  You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>        Installed: httpd-2.2.15-45.el6.centos.x86_64 (@cloudera-centos-67)
> ```

Looks like this is not a CentOS 7 but a **CentOS 6** base distribution.

Follow the [wizard](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/) instructions, selecting the proper distribution version.